# Using both b2clogin.com and custom domain with App service authentication

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door, azure-ad-b2c

We have an Azure function secured using App Service authentication (Easyauth) for local user accounts in a B2C tenant using custom policies. The function is called directly from a mobile app (XF) and this all works fine.

Recently, I followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-custom-policy in order to add a custom domain to our B2C tenant in order to avoid having to use the ‘xxxx.b2clogin.com’ endpoint. Having configured the client app to use the custom endpoints, we can successfully acquire an access token using the MS authentication libraries.

However, when attempting to access the function, we’re seeing a 401 error returned to the client. It seems as though this is because the Idp is configured with an Issuer URL in the form https://**xxxx.b2clogin.com/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com**/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={mySigninPolicy}

Indeed, if I change the Issuer URL to match the issuer claim in the token emitted by B2C, (which is now in the form https://**mycustomdomain.com/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111**/v2.0/) everything seems to work fine.

We can’t force our users to upgrade to a version of the app which uses the new endpoints, so my question is if there's any way (ideally without code changes) that the App Service authentication can handle tokens with different issuer claims?